# coming back to my app from before

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

i try to get my app done properly but i kind of stumble upon problems all the time. 
So what happens:
-> home button is pressed
-> the android menu is shown
-> i click on my app again and it just shows the appname in the actionbar and a black screen. What do i have to do to come to my starting activity again?

This screen is also shown when i press the back button. On a second tap on the back button the app closes and when i start it again it starts with my startactivity...

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

I'm calling finish() in the onPause, onStop and onDestroy.

Comment: Don't call `finish()` in `onPause()`

Comment: I removed the finish() in the onPause() but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Remove finish() from onStop() too and try.

Comment: I think you should study this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html  There is a nice graph that shows you just what happens when you close your activity on back, or home, etc...